# Npm update - npm ERR! syscall rename

Tags: node.js, npm, rename

in my project, I want to make a `npm update`, but I've always this kind of error :

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\bootswatch
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\.bootswatch-9Qtq80Xi
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\bootswatch' -> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\.bootswatch-9Qtq80Xi'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\bootswatch' -> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\node_modules\.bootswatch-9Qtq80Xi
'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SylviaTest\\node_modules\\bootswatch',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SylviaTest\\node_modules\\.bootswatch-9Qtq80Xi'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried :

- Remove packages.lock
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install
- npm install -g npm

but always this error...
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Are you running npm install from a VS Code terminal? Try closing VS Code and running the update from a CMD oder powershell window.

Comment: I'm running npm on PHP Storm terminal. I removed node_modules folder, and tried `npm install`, but I've many warning and final error `npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/css-what/-/css-what-3.4.2.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
`

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else having this issue: make sure there is nothing open that might be using those files.

- if the project server is running, close it.
- if you have the project open in an IDE, close it.
- if you have some of the files open in file explore, close it.

Then try the npm command again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try reinstalling node and npm. It was the only solution that worked for me.